# Parse Xml response from a get method in C# using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, getmethod

I have following url which returns me XML response in c#:
http://www.bnr.ro/files/xml/years/nbrfxrates2017.xml

Now, i want to retrieve the currency in Euro for my date which is present as a paramater in my function. I want to use Linq but i have some problems

My function:

```
public static void  getXml(String year, String data)
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            string url = "http://www.bnr.ro/files/xml/years/nbrfxrates" + year + ".xml";
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
            XElement xe = XElement.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
            var x = (from e in xe.Elements("Cube")
                     where e.Attribute("date").Value.Equals(data)
                     select e.Element("Rate") into p
                     where p.Element("currency").Value.Equals(data)
                     select p.Value);


            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());


        }
```

My error is:

> The root element is missing on XElement xe =
>   XElement.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

Comment: And your question is...? What problems are you having?

Comment: *"but i have some problems"* - your problems can be solved by some solutions

Comment: so does the response have a root element?

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama please look at the link

Comment: Why are you creating an `XmlDocument`, loading the response stream in - and then completely forgetting about it? And then trying to create an `XElement` separately? Your error is because you're trying to read the stream again into an element (why?). You don't need both.

Answer (score 1):

Method [GetResponseStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a stream:

> Gets the stream that is used to read the body of the response from the
>   server.

You cannot read this stream twice. When you load `XmlDocument` it reads data from network stream and closes it releasing the connection. When you try to load `XElement` from the closed stream, you get an error.

You should read response stream only once - e.g. into string or into MemoryStream:

```
string xml;
using(var reader = new StreamReader(r.GetResponseStream()))
    xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Note: It's not clear why you need `XmlDocument` if you are using linq to xml.

Comment: you are right, but my x is not return what i hope so

Comment: @S.over17 that is another problem not related to the question. Create new question and provide actual/expected results with problem description

Comment: @S.over17 I rolled back the question to original state. See my previous comment